# How to sftp file using curl and change the file permission?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I am inside server-A and trying to copy a file to a specific directory of server-B and then want to change the file permission inside server-B after copy.

I am running the below command in Server-A

```
curl --insecure --user user1:psswd1 -T ./tmp/xml-file/D-2022-TEST1.xml sftp://server-B:/mappings/ && chmod 775 ./mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml
```

The file got copied and the command was completed successfully without any error but the permission part not working. I don't see the change in the permission of file in the destination server.

outputs:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   425    0     0  100   425      0   1839 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1839
100   425    0     0  100   425      0   1839 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1839
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste exactly the code you tried, not *something like* your code. Please write more details about how exactly it is "not working". What actually happens, what is the result and what would you expect instead. Copy&paste any error message(s) you might get.

Comment: I have edited the post. hope this is more clearer now.

Comment: Do you have a local file `./mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml`? If not I would expect an error message of the `chmod` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your command consists of two parts

```
curl --insecure --user user1:psswd1 -T ./tmp/xml-file/D-2022-TEST1.xml sftp://server-B:/mappings/
```

which copies the file to `server-B` using `curl`, and

```
chmod 775 ./mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml
```

which changes the permissions of a **local file** `./mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml` if it exists.

If you want to execute this command on the remote `server-B` you might need `ssh` (and  maybe `sshpass`, e.g.

```
ssh user1@server-B chmod 775 ./mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml
```

To avoid password prompting use [`sshpass`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass).

---

Try `curl`'s option `--create-file-mode <mode>`

```
curl --insecure --user user1:psswd1 --create-file-mode 775 -T ./tmp/xml-file/D-2022-TEST1.xml sftp://server-B:/mappings/
```

---

An alternative solution would be `curl`'s [`-Q` or `--quote` option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-Q).

> -Q, --quote
>
> (FTP SFTP) Send an arbitrary command to the remote FTP or SFTP server. Quote commands are sent BEFORE the transfer takes place (just after the initial PWD command in an FTP transfer, to be exact). To make commands take place after a successful transfer, prefix them with a dash '-'. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> chmod mode file
>
> The chmod command modifies the file mode bits of the specified file. The mode operand is an octal integer mode number.

Try

```
curl --insecure --user user1:psswd1 -Q "-chmod 775 /mappings/D-2022-TEST1.xml" -T ./tmp/xml-file/D-2022-TEST1.xml sftp://server-B:/mappings/
```

Comment: I can not use the chmod with ssh to avoid password prompting and I am not allowed to set up key-based auth so trying curl approach. 
The above alternate curl solution throws below error 

Warning: The file name argument '-Q' looks like a flag.
curl: Can't open '-Q'!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Comment: @ChinmayNayak I fixed the order of the options and added another solution because I just found the `--create-file-mode` option. To avoid password prompting use `sshpass`.

Comment: Tried the updated one with creates file mode but it's not changing the file permission after copy.

Comment: @ChinmayNayak Please try **all** suggested solutions. I don't have an SFTP server, so I cannot test the commands. Did you remove the destination file before testing with `--create-file-mode`? This option may not change the permissions if the file already exists.